# Passing data in Collection View Cell

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have 1 colleection view with 4 cells which scrolls horizontal just like old youtube ios app. Under these 4 cells, each cell has custom collection view cell with 4 rows scrolls vertically. Under these rows there are customized collection view which scroll horizontally like netflix app with customized collection view cell. How do i pass data from these inner cells to a view controller with naviagation controller. No storyboard are been used. I can not push view controller from collection view cell. Also protocols are not working from inner cells. Any alternative?

Comment: show your protocol code ? Its always good to show some relevant code to fix issue.

Comment: You can use anyone of **Closure**, **protocol-delegate**, **NotificationCenter**. All are working. Definatly you done somthg wrng so pls check everything properly. If still you need help then post your code here.

Comment: only possible if you use NotificationCenter, the other methods does not work, i was pushing variables from inner cells to view controller. thanks guys @dahiya_boy

Comment: @AllyMakongo Other methods also work, it all depends on how you tackle the situation. I never used Notification. My all work are done by other two methods. Enjy buddy.